# Qualifying Exam question

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently studying for an algebraic topology exam and I am very much stuck on the following question.  I will appreciate any help.

Let $X$ be the 1-point compactification of $S^3 \times \mathbb{R}$.  Prove that $X$ is not a manifold and compute its homology groups $H_*(X, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I would start by using the homemorphism $$\phi:(a,b,c,d)\times t\mapsto e^t(a,b,c,d)$$ from $S^3\times \mathbb{R}$ to $V=\mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{(0,0,0,0)\}$. It is easy to see what the compact sets on $V$ look like: bounded, closed, miss a ball about the origin.

Answer (score 4):

A one point compactification of $S^3\times \Bbb R$ is given by $$X = (S^3\times [0,1])/(S^3\times \{0\} \cup S^3 \times \{1\})$$ since we can extend a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon \Bbb R \to (0,1)$ to a homeomorphism $\text{id}\times \varphi\colon S^3\times \Bbb R \to S^3\times (0,1)$.

To see that this isn't a manifold, let $p$ be the image of $S^3\times \{0\}$ in $X$. Then observe that there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathring{D^4} \vee \mathring{D^4}$, where by $\vee$ I mean [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum), $p$ being the point where the two discs are joined. In particular, this means that there is no open neighourhood of $p$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.

To compute its homology groups use the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence.

Comment: Dear A.P. your description of $p$ is incorrect.

Comment: Dear @Georges, you are right. I shamefully yanked (as in copy/paste) the wrong part of the definition of $X$ and didn't check it. Should be fixed now.